# hiding panel and showing JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea

I am trying to un-hide a text area with a button on panel at the same place.

The code is like:

```
public class experiment {

public static void main(String[] args){
    final JFrame f = new JFrame("experiment");
    final JTextArea tx = new JTextArea();
    final JPanel pn = new JPanel();
    final JButton bt = new JButton("click me");
    f.setSize(500,500);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(tx);
    tx.setText("hello");
    f.add(pn);
    pn.add(bt);
    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            pn.remove(bt);
            f.remove(pn);

        }



    });
 }}
```

but it is not showing me the text area with text inside it..

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: If you think its not useful...or easy so why you have not replayed the ans. which is still not giving the desired output...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure if I got your question. You want to, when the button is pressed, show a TextArea, is it correct?
If this is what you want, you should try to use CardLayout. Here is one tutorial about it.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

I hope I could help

Comment: +1, yes using a CardLayout is the preferred approach. @user2761414, you have been given code. The tutorial contains a working example. Read the tutorial and ask a specific question with the code you tried if you have a problem. Also, when you download and text the given example notice the better way to structure your program. All Swing code should execute on the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the content panel of the frame for adding the text area instead of adding directly in the frame. You can get the content pane via `f.getContentPane()`.

Then you need some layout to manage the position of components. Here is an example using BorderLayout.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame f = new JFrame("experiment");
    final JPanel pn = new JPanel();
    final JButton bt = new JButton("click me");
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(pn);
    pn.add(bt);
    final JTextArea tx = new JTextArea();
    f.getContentPane().add(tx, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.getContentPane().add(pn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    tx.setText("hello");
    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            pn.remove(bt);
            f.remove(pn);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for good reply .. But the code is not removing the panel until or unless i start typing into the text area...

Comment: You might wanna try `pn.setvisibility(false)`

Comment: i guess there is no method like that @darkprince

Comment: Correction. Method is `pn.setVisible(false)`;